# How to wrap OffContent/OnContent of a ToggleSwitch in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, toggleswitch

OffContent/OnContent in custom toggle switch doesn't fit into one line because it has custom text and cell in the grid (where ToggleSwitch is placed) isn't wide enough.

Off/OnContent stretches beyond boundaries of ToggleSwitch element even when I define custom templates for OffContentTemplate and OnContentTemplate

[Problem example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6GF0.jpg)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ToggleSwitchTextBlockTemplate">
    <TextBlock
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="{Binding}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</DataTemplate>

<ToggleSwitch
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    x:Name="SomeToggle"
    Header="Some header"
    OffContent="Off content to verify if string is wrapped"
    OnContent="On content to verify if string is wrapped"
    OffContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTextBlockTemplate}"
    OnContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTextBlockTemplate}"
    Width="200" />
```

How do I force Off/OnContent to wrap and fit into ToggleSwitch boundaries?

[Desired results, where Off/OnContent is wrapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJuQH.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the style of ToggleSwitch, there are OffContentPresenter and OnContentPresenter represent OffContent and OnContent, you could add the TextWrapping to wrap the content and set Width to limit its width. About the complete style, you can go to generic.xaml to copy it.

.xaml:

```
       <Style x:Key="ToggleSwitchStyle1" TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
            ......
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                ......
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchHeaderForeground}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchTopHeaderMargin}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThemeMinWidth}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="12" Width="12"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchPreContentMargin}"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchPostContentMargin}"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid x:Name="SwitchAreaGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackground}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" Margin="0,5" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                <ContentPresenter TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100" x:Name="OffContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OffContent}" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100" x:Name="OnContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OnContent}" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                ......

                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Or you can also put a TextBlock in the ToggleSwitch's OnContent and OffContent properties to achieve it.

```
<ToggleSwitch Width="200" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="SomeToggle" 
              Header="Some header" >
    <ToggleSwitch.OffContent>
        <TextBlock Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap">Off content to verify if string is wrapped</TextBlock>
    </ToggleSwitch.OffContent>
</ToggleSwitch>
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to set Width to limit its width directly, you could change the ColumnDefinition from "Auto" to " * ". The "Auto" means that a column is given as much width as the elements within it require. But the " * " is based on the width of the remaining space. So when you set the ColumnDefinition to " * ", it will place your text according to the remaining space, and will wrap it if not enough.

The style part that need to be modified is(you just need to change the following part from the original style):

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThemeMinWidth}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="12" Width="12"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ......
</Grid>
```

Usage:

```
<ToggleSwitch
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    x:Name="SomeToggle"
    Header="Some header"
    OffContent="Off content to verify if string is wrapped"
    OnContent="On content to verify if string is wrapped"
    OffContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTextBlockTemplate}"
    OnContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTextBlockTemplate}"
    Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyle1}"
    Width="200" />
```

Comment: Both examples rely on **[Width="100"]**. It doesn't wrap Off/OnContent at the right place, but at hard-coded 100 width.    
  
Post has a [problem example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6GF0.jpg). Size of Off/OnContent extends way past ToggleSwitch size that's why it doesn't get wrapped. If I used hard-coded 100 value I could have as easily use in custom DataTemplate with TextBlock in the original post.

Comment: Width of the 0th column is already set to 200. If you look at example above, width ToggleSwitch element is already within Grid's column width. Off/On Content stretches beyond the boundaries of both ToggleSwitch and Grid.

Answer (score 0):

I did all Faywang suggested with no result whatsoever.
I noticed, when I set OffContent directly (instead of defining a template) and check properties of elements

```
        <ToggleSwitch
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            x:Name="SomeToggle"
            Header="Some header"
            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTextBlockTemplate}"
            OnContent="On content to verify if string is wrapped"
            OnContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTextBlockTemplate}"
            Width="200">
            <ToggleSwitch.OffContent>
                <TextBlock
                    Width="Auto"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="Off content to verify if string is wrapped" />
            </ToggleSwitch.OffContent>
        </ToggleSwitch>
```

Width of ToggleSwitch is 200. But width of OffContent's TextBlock is "Auto (246.224)". Just like in my example where it stretches far beyond parent's element. As a result it won't wrap as expected.

My take on this, this is a bug in behavior of ToggleSwitch. ToggleSwitch is supposed to arrange layout of its children. Say, if Width of ToggleSwitch element is 200, give 40 to Toggle and 160 to OffContent/OnContent. This is just a theory of how it is implemented, not the actual numbers.
Since OffContent/OnContent is almost always one short word (either "Off/On" or "No/Yes") and doesn't span multiple lines, Microsoft never tested this test case.